# Ruby Timezones — to UTC and back

Tags: mysql, ruby, timezone, dst

I run a scheduling site that allows users to set a timezone for their account. They can then schedule 'posts' on a calendar for that timezone. In the back-end, I take the time and convert it into UTC time (where a worker processes and picks up those posts on UTC time).

I run the site on Ruby (with Puma/Sinatra), but without Rails, and I'd like to stay away from Rails. There's HTML/ERB/JS in the front and a MYSQL backend.

I thought that simply adding/subtracting UTC offsets will solve all problems. I have a simple list that has `TIMEZONE <--> UTCOFFSET` and this worked very well — or so I thought.

And then I realised this does not work when a given timezone (or place) is in DST currently.

*Vienna in the summer: UTC offset: +2h*

*Vienna in the winter: UTC offset: +1h*

Is there a simple way to give Ruby (not Rails) a "timezone ID" and receive the correct adjusted UTC offset back?

Like:

```
user.timezone = "Europe/Vienna"
utc_adjusted_time = post.local_time.to_i + get_utc_offset(user.timezone)
```

Where `get_utc_offset` *knows* whether it is in DST or not. Any ideas?

I've gone through the IANA database (which is absolute overkill), I've searched through numerous Gists on Github, I've tried to abuse whatever Rails seemed to have, but didn't get very far.

How do you guys handle this? Ideally, as said, each post will be converted and saved to a DST-stripped UTC time. Thanks!

Comment: `get_utc_offset` would need to know whether it's in DST *for local_time*. Not currently. Basically, you need a proper time zone class, e.g. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html - but that looks like it's from Rails. (I'm not a Ruby person, so may have some naive assumptions around what you can use). Note that a local-to-UTC mapping may be impossible or ambiguous if the local time is around a DST transition. (e.g. when springing forward, 1:30am may not exist at all; when falling back 1:30am may occur twice). You need to work out your desired behaviour.

Comment: You might also want to consider storing the time zone and local time, instead of UTC, bearing in mind that rules can change over time... by the time your scheduled event occurs, it might not be at the local time that the user originally specified, if you go ahead with storing UTC.

Comment: _Offtopic_: Ruby 1.6 release notes contain that commit comment from Matz: https://speakerdeck.com/skade/the-dark-side-of-matz-1?slide=11

Comment: @JonSkeet the odd case of ambiguous time will likely be very much an edge case I am willing to compromise not supporting for now (99.99% of all posts are within business hours) — and with regards to storing the original time/timezone — yes, I do that as well, just didn't mention it.

Comment: https://github.com/panthomakos/timezone , well used this one in my application run quite fine. Hope if this helps.

Comment: @MuaazRafi thanks for the link — this looks great. But for the amount of posts we're processing, I doubt we can get by depending on a public API of two different providers. This would greatly impact our service (complete shut-down) if one of the two becomes unavailable (Google especially has a bad API history in my experience, reg. Charts, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Ruby [TZInfo gem](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/file/README.md).

Your use case is exactly the one shown [in the readme](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/file/README.md):

```
require 'tzinfo'

tz = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')
local = tz.utc_to_local(Time.utc(2005,8,29,15,35,0))

utc = tz.local_to_utc(local)

period = tz.period_for_utc(Time.utc(2005,8,29,15,35,0))
id = period.zone_identifier
```

Looking at the docs for [`TZInfo::TimePeriod`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/tzinfo/TZInfo/TimezonePeriod) you can see the other information you asked about:

```
period.offset
period.dst?
```

... etc.

FYI - the Rails time zone support is based on this gem anyway.  Then Rails goes and puts some funky aliasing over the top (which I advise against using).  See the section on Rails in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).